# rijndael 128 cfb C# and php

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, rijndael

I have a problem. I have a method to encrypt a password in php and in C# but i cannot get the same results with both algorithms. Someone can help me?

PhP

```
<?php

$password = 'MySecretPass';
$secret = '65rgt85k89xrDAr3';
$iv = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';


$td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cfb','');
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $secret, $iv);

$password = mcrypt_generic($td, $password);

mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);

$password=base64_encode($password);

echo $password;

?>
```

C#

```
var password = padString("MySecretPass");
txtEncrypt.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptStringToBytes(password,
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("65rgt85k89xrDAr3"), 
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"), PaddingMode.None));
txtEncrypt.Text = txtEncrypt.Text;


static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv, PaddingMode mode)
{
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CFB, BlockSize = 128, Padding = mode })
    {
        rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iv;

                var encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
    return encrypted;
}

     private static String padString(String source)
     {
         char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
         int x = source.Length % size;
         int padLength = size - x;

         for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
         {
             source += paddingChar;
         }

         return source;
     }
```

The results for PhP is "/KNlzi/fZOERWL79", but for c# is /J643dvAR4/Gh0aYHdshNw==. I don't know why my results are different. In addition, I have wrote the code in Java and I get the same result than in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you just share your *secret* key with the world?

Comment: is a random word. Is not the real secret key.

Comment: You could also quickly test with CBC; CBC has less pecularities than CFB, so if the ciphertext is identical using CBC, then the difference is in the CFB parameters.

Comment: I have changed to CBC and i get different results rfgcnO3PPP1uXzBXKvIYiQ== in php and chlsxEsrCQEQUWXVPZvGA== in .net

Comment: The .NET version is not a multiple of 4 characters. Please check and post again.

Comment: the code works fine, the password is multiple of 4, this is the meaning of padString

Comment: Unless I'm completely off, I count 23 characters in the "chlsxEsrCQEQUWXVPZvGA==" string you've put in your comment. This may be a copy/paste error, but a fact's a fact.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that `Encoding.GetBytes(string)` returns "Unicode encoding". That's an encoding that actually does not exist, but it returns UTF-16. On the other hand you treat your key and IV as ASCII characters.

So whichever encoding PHP is using at the time, there will be a mismatch. You should *explicitly* define which encoding should be used when converting textual strings to bytes, both in the PHP code as in your C# code.

Comment: I have put the same encoding (Utf-8 and ASCII) and i'm still having differences between both

Comment: Do you now get the same size ciphertext at least? Could you post updated results and changes you made (below your original question?)